# Outlook opening some messages has weird artifact

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook, when I open certain messages, there is a fade in the top right corner (see picture). This happens infrequently, but is repeatable for the same message (though I haven't tested across system restarts).  Any ideas why it happens?  Note that it does not appear for most messages.

[image: Weird fade over minimize/maximize/close icons]

For reference this is what the rest of my messages look like. Note that the message with the fade is flagged as a task, but other flagged tasks do not show this behaviour. I do not remember if the previous messages that had this behaviour were flagged.

[image: Normal minimize/maximize/close icons]

Comment: Based on your pictures my guess is that it's shadow/high-lighting being applied to the text in the title bar.  Notice in the affected one the title is really long (visible in picture -- "...et UDF M") where as the other is not...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Wow... That's probably it... Don't know how I didn't see that.  Well mystery solved.  If you think it's worth answering do it and I'll accept, otherwise I'll delete it.

Comment: I'll happily add it as an answer if you confirm it's the cause in your copy of Outlook (I don't have Outlook 2010 here to test, we're on 2013, and it's UI is much different in that area ;) ).  Perhaps just send yourself an email with a really long title and see if it acts the same way. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I just tried a bunch of different messages, and that seems to be the pattern (replicated twice so far).

Comment: nice, Ok I added my comment as an answer.  Good luck with the rest of your day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your pictures it appears that it's shadow/high-lighting being applied to the text in the title bar.

Notice in the affected one the title is really long (visible in picture -- "...et UDF M") where as the other is not.